# Nextjs 12 stop updating on a component that is inside a dynamic route

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic, components, updating

I have a problem where a component that I render inside a dynamic route stop updating in the developer mode. I have the component inside a list and I put that in the JSX. The image is for how the code looks like

[image: Code of component not updating inside a dynamic route]